# Xcode git is not committing project.pbxproj

Tags: xcode, git, push, commit

I have a remote git repository and I am trying to commit and push my latest changes.  The problem is that everything commits fine except for project.pbxproj.  Xcode does not complain. It just acts as if all committed with no issues.  But when I push it complains that there are uncommitted changes.  So I try to commit again.  It shows that there are changes in the project.pbxproj.  Fine.  This has happened before. I have just committed again and all is good.  But not this time.  I commit.  Xcode has no complaints until I try to push.  So I try to commit again and I see that it really did not commit because the differences are the same as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the log navigator can help you find what's causing the problem. Choose View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator to open the log navigator. Select the commit from the log navigator. The editor will look similar to the following screenshot:

[image]

On the right side of the blue area of the screenshot is a small button. Click that button to open the transcript, which can help you determine why the commit is not working.

Comment: Here is the transcript:git commit -m trying to get project.pbcproj to commit -- /Users/jigoossen/Desktop/Programming/app_store/Snake/Snake.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj  
# On branch master  
# Your branch is ahead of 'master/master' by 3 commits.  
#  
# Changes not staged for commit:  
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)  
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)  
#  
# modified:   Snake.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj  
#  
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get any of the markdown formatting to work.  I am a newbie to git so that really doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Xcode can't commit your changes because they have not been staged, but you cannot explicitly stage changes from Xcode. You will have to do your commit from outside Xcode, either from the command line or from a git GUI client like gitX.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you.  I tried first in terminal, but didn't know what to do, but gitX worked great!!

Comment: Your answer worked, but with this project and only this project it happens nearly every time I commit.  It's a real pain having to go to gitX every time to stage it.  Any ideas as to how to fix the project itself?

Comment: I don't know how to fix the project. If you have a paid Apple developer account, ask about this on their forums. If not, ask on Apple's Xcode mailing list. One of the Xcode engineers may have an answer for you.